# CSS - Styling a form

Tags: html, css

I'm styling a form for a site and I need it to look like this - 
[image: PSD Version]

My coded version, so far, looks like this - 
[image: Coded version]

The name & email sections for some reason won't size properly and there seems to be padding or margin properties somewhere which I can't seem to override. Here's my code as it stands -

```css
form {
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
  margin-right: 50px;
}

.name {
  float: left;
}

input[type=text],
input[type=email] {
  background: #F0F0F0;
  font-size: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
}

input[type=subject] {
  background: #F0F0F0;
  font-size: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
}

textarea {
  resize: vertical;
  font-size: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #F0F0F0;
  height: 100px;
}

input[type=submit] {
  background: #00bfff;
  border: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: 700;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="six columns">
  <form>
    <fieldset>
      <div class="name">
        <input type="text" required placeholder="NAME">
      </div>
      <div class="name">
        <input type="email" required placeholder="EMAIL">
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="subject" placeholder="SUBJECT">
      </div>
      <div>
        <textarea placeholder="MESSAGE..."></textarea>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
    <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT">
  </form>
</div>
```

UPDATE - Latest version.
[image: Latest attempt]

Comment: What happens if you try this: give your email div a class of "email" and in your css: `.email {  float: left; margin-left: 10px !important; }`

Comment: @Arman It makes it one long section but when I try and apply any width rules to make it line up with the name section nothing happens.

Comment: This appears to work for me: [https://jsfiddle.net/xw2keum0/1/](https://jsfiddle.net/xw2keum0/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a bunch of tweaks and kind of last track as I went, so I hope you're able to read through this and figure it out. If not, please feel free to ask questions!

```css
form {
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
  margin-right: 50px;
}

fieldset {
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
}

div.row {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

div.row input {
  margin-left: 5px;
}
div.row input:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}

input[type=text],
input[type=email] {
  background: #E8E8E8;
  font-size: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding: 6px 12px;
}

textarea {
  resize: none;
  font-size: 10px;
  background: #E8E8E8;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 0;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

input[type=submit] {
  background: #1ba4dd;
  border: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: 700;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 8px 0;
}

input[type=submit]:hover {
  background: #00bfff;
}
```

```html
<div class="six columns">
  <form>
    <fieldset>
      <div class="row">
        <input name="name" type="text" required placeholder="NAME">
        <input name="email" type="email" required placeholder="EMAIL">
      </div>
      <input name="subject" type="text" placeholder="SUBJECT">
      <textarea rows="8" placeholder="MESSAGE..."></textarea>
    </fieldset>
    <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT">
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: i have a .row rule for height (250px) and margin-top (20px) , how can I override this for the form because its leaving a huge gap between the name/email fields and the rest of the form as things stand?

Comment: You mean you already have a class called `row`? Just pick a different class name, or maybe make a more specific rule (like `form#thisparticularform div.row`).

Comment: I've just updated the answer to illustrate how it looks. I've updated the other rows in the css file so I know it's not them conflicting. What could be causing this gap?

Comment: How would I know? That's presumably caused by some CSS that you haven't shared. I would suggest inspecting the element in the browser to see what's happening.